# Purple snow in skyrim, what is causing this?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started a new Skyrim game and I noticed that the colour/texture of snowy rocks seemed off. It is a bright bluey purple colour that really ruins the immersion of the game for me.

[image]

I deactivated all mods and expansions and deleted my skyrim folder and redownloaded it from steam.

Same problem.

Can I try anything else? Or am I colour blind / monitor issue?

Comment: Has Skyrim worked on that PC & monitor before?

Comment: Yeah, it's been a long time since I've played though.

Comment: Has your graphics card changed since then? Are its drivers up to date?

Comment: Try reloading from a previous save?

Comment: @Studoku I might have changed my card. Drivers are up to date. TheUnicornMaster It is a new game...

Comment: That's a missing texture. How many mods do you have installed?

Comment: I had several 4k texture packs installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I thought I was looking at snow. I was actually looking at a rock texture. A broken rock texture. When I told steam to delete skyrim and redownload it again it didn't wipe out a texture folder.

In my `SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim\Data` folder there was a suspicious folder named "textures" I deleted it and now it works!
Must have been a remnant of an old mod.

Comment: Well, great job finding the solution. If this is the answer you're looking for, click on the check mark on the left of the answer to make it marked accepted.